# Facebook comment box connected to a certain photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Im planning to show some facebook album pictures on a remote page. I would like to connect a facebook comment box (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to each photo. What url should i paste in the url attribute on the comment box to connect it with the comments posted on facebook? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the url that will take you directly to the photo itself (ie: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=###&set=a.###). You can locate this url by right clicking one of your images in the thumbnail view and opening it in a new tab. Rather than opening it in the standard image viewer, it will open it a new tab by itself.

Comment: Ok, and how would i get the url using the graph api?

Comment: The photo object contains a "link" property. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/. You can also get this using FQL.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  If I use the tool on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ and paste the url for a photo no comments are shown. Johan, did it work for you?

Comment: hey Johan, Zoran this even did not worked for me. I am missing something on href. Can anybody help on this. How to use FB:Comment box for viewing and posting comments on facebook photos. I am developing some photo viewer which shows FB photos and allows users to comment from there.

Comment: This post is well over a year old. Facebook changes their APIs and conventions all of the time, so I'm sure it's just obsolete at this point. The suggestion obviously worked at the time as it was an accepted solution, so there's no reason to down vote it a year later.